# How to hide the first column in the GridView that will be generated using the StoredProcedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net

***I am using a GridView inside a Repeater control*** to generate three GridViews with 3 similar columns and different number of different columns between them. Everything works fine and well. I am just facing one probelm with the filtered results.
I have a Filter as dropdownlist based on the Division name. This filter shows the following values: All and the division names which are retrieved from the database.
Instead of showing the division name when I filtered the results based on the one of these divisions, I hide the Division column programmatically.

Now, I want when the value of filter is All to show the Division column when it is other than All value to show that column. So how to do that?

My ASP.NET code:

```
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDivision" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
        AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="sqlDataSourceDivision" DataTextField="DivisionName" 
        DataValueField="DivisionName"  
        Width="275px" EnableViewState="False">
        <asp:ListItem Value="%">All</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

   <strong> Search </strong>
    <input id=id_search type=text placeholder="Search">


     <br />  <br />  
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("GroupID")%>' />

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
                                    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="kbiReport"
                                    FilterExpression="[DivisionName] like '{0}%'">

                    <FilterParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDivision" Name="DivisionName" 
                                                 PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                    </FilterParameters>

                    <SelectParameters>
                        <%--ControlParameter is linked to the HiddenField above to generate different GridView based on different values 
                            of GroupID--%>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenField1" Name="GroupID" PropertyName="Value" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>

                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
                                AllowSorting="True" 
                                CellPadding="3" 
                                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                                ClientIDMode="Static" class="fixedTables" Width="600" AutoGenerateColumns="true"
                                AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" 
                                RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                                OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnPreRender="GridView1_PreRender" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated"
                                OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    <HeaderStyle Font-Bold = "true" ForeColor="Black"/> 
                    <Columns>
                    </Columns>
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
                </asp:GridView>

                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                           ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>"
                           SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT GroupID FROM courses">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <%--Filtering by Division--%>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDataSourceDivision" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [DivisionName] FROM [Divisions]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And the code-behind for hiding the first column is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Repeater1.DataBind();

    }


    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            GridView gv = e.Item.FindControl("GridView1") as GridView;
            if (gv != null)
            {

                gv.DataBind();
                if (ddlDivision.SelectedValue != "ALL")
                {
                    if (gv.Columns.Count > 0)
                        gv.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                    else
                    {
                        gv.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
                        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gv.Rows)
                        {
                            gvr.Cells[0].Visible = false;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try hiding the column just after the databind() call..

```
GridView1.DataBind();
if (GridView1.Columns.Count > 0)
    GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
else
{
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        gvr.Cells[0].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
    void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
                {
                    GridView gv = e.Item.FindControl("GridView1") as GridView;
                    if (gv != null )
                    {

                        gv.DataBind();
                        if(ddlMyList.SelectedText != "ALL")
                        {
                        if (gv.Columns.Count > 0)
                            gv.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                        else
                        {
                            gv.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
                            foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gv.Rows)
                            {
                                gvr.Cells[0].Visible = false;
                            }
                        }
                     }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Should I put this in the Page_Load()?

Comment: By the way, this GridView is inside a Repeater so how I will be able to bind it?

Comment: yes you can use it in if(!IsPostback).. if you want to hide column on specific control event you can use it in its handler.

Comment: if you gridview is nested then you will have to call databind in repeater's ItemDataBound after finding the grid control in it using e.findcontrol().

Comment: Could you please provide me with code? I am a new to this area

Comment: Thanks but should I put this code inside the Page_Load() or outside it?

Comment: just call databind() on repeater on pageload. and rest of the code will be in repeater's ItemDataBound event handler as it shown in the code

Comment: Besides that I don't see anything related to the selected value of the DropDownList Filter. As explained above, if the value is "ALL" the first column should be appeared. If it is other than "ALL" the first column should be disappeared.

Comment: is dropdown is outside the repeater?

Comment: Yes, it is outside the Repeater

Comment: add if(ddlMyList.SelectedText != "ALL") after DataBind() call of gridview

Comment: Sorry but I confused with the DataBind() of repeater and gridview, Could you please explain to me in code where I should put these stuff?

Comment: in pageload call rpt.DataBind(). GridView's databind is already shown in the code. it should be in rpt_ItemDataBound

Comment: I got the following error: The SqlDataSource control 'SqlDataSource1' does not have a naming container.  Ensure that the control is added to the page before calling DataBind

Comment: can you give the code.. how repeater and grid are placed. with code for pageload and rpt.ItemDataBound

Comment: Thanks for your continuous help. Please see the edited code in my question above

Comment: are you getting this error on Repeater1.DataBind();?? try commenting this line

Comment: Yeah, I got an error with line and when I commented it Everything works fine except that the first column will not be hidden or disappeared if the value of the DropDownList different than ALL

Comment: try changing the index 0 in GridView1.Columns[0] to the column you want to hide.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false; // hides the first column
    }
```